# can you run functions multiple times swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm working on a game in Swift Playgrounds, and I'm trying to make a function run multiple times when a variable changes. Here is the code I have below

```
    public override func mouseDown(with event1: NSEvent) {
        NP = self.childNode(withName: "NP") as? SKLabelNode
        txt = self.childNode(withName: "Talking") as? SKLabelNode

        let point1 = event1.location(in: self)
        let hitnodes1 = self.nodes(at: point1)

        var counter = 0

        if hitnodes1.contains(where: {$0.name == "NP"}) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                txt.text = "Test2"

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {counter += 1}
                //wait here so that it doest automatically go to the next one
            }
            if (counter == 1) {
                    txt.text = "Test3"

                counter += 1
                }

                
        }
    }
```

I think the issue lies with my counter, but it may be with the function itself. does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue? Any help would be amazing :)

Comment: What function are you trying to call multiple times.  I assume it's supposed to be controlled by `counter` that you want updated by the `asyncAfter` closure.  But I don't see any thing that would invoke a function.  Are you trying to simulate the mouse clicking a second time?

Comment: @ChipJarred yes, I am trying to simulate a mouse clicking a second time. is there a way to do this other than the way I have done it?

Comment: There are multiple ways you could do it.  I'm about to post an answer with one possibility.

Comment: Your question got me thinking of more ways to do it.  You could re-send the event using `NSApp.sendEvent` to re-send the event through the normal mechanism.  In that case you need a way to keep the counter live.  You could make it a property of your view, or you could use the `userData` property of `NSEvent`, but it's an `UnsafeRawMutablePointer` so you'd be responsible for allocating and deallocating it.

Answer (score 1):

If understand what you're trying to do (and it's entirely possible that I don't), I think something along these lines will do it:

```swift
    public override func mouseDown(with event1: NSEvent) {
        mouseDown(with: event1, counter: 0)
    }
    
    private func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent, counter: Int)
    {
        NP = self.childNode(withName: "NP") as? SKLabelNode
        txt = self.childNode(withName: "Talking") as? SKLabelNode

        let point1 = event1.location(in: self)
        let hitnodes1 = self.nodes(at: point1)

        if hitnodes1.contains(where: {$0.name == "NP"})
        {
            switch counter
            {
                case 0:
                    txt.text = "Test2"
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        self.mouseDown(with: event, counter: counter + 1)
                    }
                    //wait here so that it doest automatically go to the next one

                case 1:
                    txt.text = "Test3"
                    // This will actually generate a 3rd mouse click
                    mouseDown(with: event, counter: counter + 1)

                default: break
            }
        }
    }
```

As David Wheeler is credited as saying, "You can solve any problem by adding a layer of indirection."  In this case, by having the actual AppKit `mouseDown` call a private one that takes a counter parameter, you can then call the one with the counter directly from `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter`

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! This is great :)

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful